# Url rewriting: .htaccess not loading images css and js on localhost Wamp server

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting, localhost, wamp

I have followed the rule for .htaccess rewriting for my Localhost as :

```
RewriteEngine on

This is my root folder (slug)

RewriteBase /slug/

RewriteRule ^gallery_images/([^/]*)$ gallery_images.php?slug=$1

RewriteRule ^gallery_images/(css|js|img)/(.*)?$ $1
```

it will redirect from `gallery_images/some_text` to  `gallery_images.php?slug=some_text`

but the images, css and js file is not loaded.

css folder: `slug/css/`

js folder: `slug/js/`

image folder: `slug/img/`

Comment: `RewriteRule ^gallery_images/((?:css|js|img)/.+)$ $1 [L]`

Comment: Actually the page is redirect to `gallery_images.php?slug=some_text` but the variable is not getting values like `slug=some_text` @Deadooshka

Comment: The `RewriteBase` is not needed if you have not to change the prefix to all paths